# nvm not found when deploying from Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, capistrano, nvm

Good evening..

Getting nvm not found while trying to deploy my node.js application from Jenkins using capistrano.

Tried with multiple solutions like, appended below code in ~/.bashrc.

```
export NVM_DIR=« $HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

But no luck. and also I have below mentioned code in my deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do 
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
     run "kill `cat /tmp/.app.pid`; true"
     run "cd #{app_path} && sudo npm install"
     run "cd #{app_path}/src; (NODE_ENV=DEV nvm exec 4.4.5 nohup node app.js &) && sleep 1"
 end 
end
```

Getting below request, When I run `nvm ls` In my build box as a **ubuntu** user

```
nvm ls
->v0.10.32  
v4.4.5  
default -> 0.10.32 (-> v0.10.32)
node -> stable (-> v4.4.5) (default)
stable -> 4.4 (-> v4.4.5) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/argon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.8.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.10.1 (-> N/A)
```

Anything wrong in my set up?

Comment: Windows has a Environmental Path, called Path, but there is also a system path.  Could this be similar to Ubuntu box, there is a local path and a system path.  i.e. your .bashrc, maybe that is only for one user/profile

Comment: (nvm maintainer here) Does Capistrano use a login shell? nvm requires one.